# Spring project cannot connect to the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, plsql

PLSQL can connect to oracle, but the project can not be connected, it will report errors when it is started, but it should not be the problem of code, because everyone of the code is pulled down from git.
I've tried re-installing jdk, re-pulling maven library, and even installing virtual machines, is still not good, or report the same error.
[image: error report 1]
[image: error report 2]
[image: error report 3]

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace. What you shared is not the important part of it. Maybe the credentials for connection are incorrect

Comment: are you able to connect to database from your application server?

Comment: Don't just go wild reinstalling everything. It is just a database connection error. If you can publish the entire log and database configuration of your application, then we will be able to help you.

Comment: PL/SQL is already within the database and part of it, so it does not connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when your database is down hence the connection refused error or your credentials are wrong. It would help if we could look at your code.